# RxJs combine http request

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, rxjs

Всем привет, подскажите есть ли возможность в RxJs скомбинировать два http запроса таким образом чтобы параметры второго запроса возвращались в первом

```
a = http.get<any>(...);
b = http.get<any>(... + accountId + userId})

concat(a, b).subscribe(res => {});
```

и собственно accountId и userId должны вернуться в запросе a можно ли как-то объеденить два запроса таким образом?

Comment: [раз](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html), [два](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html), а вообще ничего не понятно. > `параметры второго запроса возвращались в первом` - какие параметрты? зачем в первом запросе?

Comment: Наверное вы имеете в виду, что ответ первого запроса нужен для запуска второго? Тогда просто запускайте их последовательно.